# split String into Array by delimiter

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json data from API like below

```
{
    "message": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "SIPHON",
            "description": "<p><span style=\"color: #555555; font-family: Avenir-Regular; background-color: #ffffff;\">Siphon coffee was invented in the 1840s more or less simultaneously by a French housewife and Scottish marine engineer. It&rsquo;s been refined many times, but a few principles hold true: It produces a delicate, tea-like cup of coffee; it can be quite persnickety; and it is, for our money, one of the coolest brew methods available.</span></p>\r\n<p><span style=\"color: #555555; font-family: Avenir-Regular; background-color: #ffffff;\">Sumber : <a title=\"https://bluebottlecoffee.com/preparation-guides/siphon\" href=\"https://bluebottlecoffee.com/preparation-guides/siphon\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">https://bluebottlecoffee.com/preparation-guides/siphon</a></span></p>",
            "slug": "siphon",
            "image": "4cf25879ab69702dbe12c244f233f5b4_1551366184.jpg",
            "time": "{\"time1\":\"2\",\"time2\":\"3\",\"unit\":\"minute\"}",
            "temperature": "{\"temperature\":\"195\",\"unit\":\"\\u00b0F\"}",
            "ingredients": "[{\"name\":\"Coffee\",\"amount\":\"25\",\"unit\":\"gr\"},{\"name\":\"Hot Water\",\"amount\":\"300\",\"unit\":\"ml\"}]",
            "tools": "[{\"name\":\"Grinder\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"unit\":\"unit\"},{\"name\":\"Scale\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"unit\":\"unit\"},{\"name\":\"Siphon set\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"unit\":\"unit\"},{\"name\":\"Thermometer\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"unit\":\"unit\"},{\"name\":\"Timer\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"unit\":\"unit\"},{\"name\":\"Bamboo paddle\",\"amount\":\"1\",\"unit\":\"unit\"}]",
            "steps": "[\"After soaking your filter in a warm water bath for at least five minutes, drop it into the bottom of your siphon\\u2019s top component, or \\u201chopper,\\u201d and hook to the bottom of the hopper\\u2019s glass tubing.\",\"Fill your siphon\\u2019s bottom component, or \\u201cbulb,\\u201d with 300 grams of hot water (about a 12-oz. cup\\u2019s worth).\",\"Insert the hopper, filter and all, into the bulb. You don't have to press too hard; just make sure it's securely and evenly in place. Position the entire assembly above your heat source.\",\"While the water is heating, measure out between 20-25 grams of coffee and grind it just little bit finer than you would for regular drip coffee.\",\"Soon, the water in the bulb will begin boiling and rise up into the hopper. For some physics-related reason we don\\u2019t fully understand, a little bit will stay in the bottom. Don\\u2019t worry about this little bit.\",\"Once the water has moved into the hopper, turn your heat source down so that the water is between 185-195 degrees F.\",\"Add your coffee, and gently (but thoroughly) submerge it with a bamboo paddle or butter knife.\",\"Let the coffee brew, undisturbed, for one minute and 10 seconds.\",\"In one brisk motion, remove your siphon from its heat source and give it ten stirs with a bamboo paddle.\",\"Your coffee should take another minute or so to draw downward and finally rest in the bulb. You'll know it's ready when a dome of grounds has formed at the top of the filter, and when the coffee at the bottom has begun to bubble at approximately the pace and strength of a kitten\\u2019s heartbeat.\\r\\n\\r\\nRemove the hopper and serve. In order to guarantee the most complex cup, give the coffee a few minutes to cool.\"]",
            "step_images": "[\"4cf25879ab69702dbe12c244f233f5b4_11551366184.jpg\",\"4cf25879ab69702dbe12c244f233f5b4_21551366184.jpg\",\"4cf25879ab69702dbe12c244f233f5b4_31551366184.jpg\",\"4cf25879ab69702dbe12c244f233f5b4_41551366184.jpg\",\"4cf25879ab69702dbe12c244f233f5b4_51551366184.jpg\",\"4cf25879ab69702dbe12c244f233f5b4_61551366184.jpg\",\"4cf25879ab69702dbe12c244f233f5b4_71551366184.jpg\",\"4cf25879ab69702dbe12c244f233f5b4_81551366184.jpg\",\"4cf25879ab69702dbe12c244f233f5b4_91551366184.jpg\",\"4cf25879ab69702dbe12c244f233f5b4_101551366184.jpg\"]",
            "user_id": 1,
            "status_id": 1,
            "shared_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2019-02-28 15:03:04",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-28 15:03:04",
            "deleted_at": null
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is split string in **steps** and store it in array. The delimiter is **.\",** . Thanks.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: which string do you want to split? the entire object as a string or a specific property inside the object?

Comment: Can you simplify your Question with an expected output?

Comment: What I expected is get an array like this
`["After soaking your filter in a warm water . . . glass tubing.", "Fill your . . . hot water worth).", "Insert the hopper, filter and all, into the bulb. You don't have to press too hard; just make sure it's securely and evenly in place. Position the entire assembly above your heat source."];`

Answer (score 0):

You have to first parse the JSON by:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(yourJsonStringObject)
```

after that,

```
let arrayOfSteps = obj.data[0].steps.split(".\")
```

Answer (score 0):

**steps** is string so you can parse your output like this:

Let's say if you have stored the above json in variable **apiResponse**;

Then get the parsed string:

```
var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(apiResponse["data"][0]["steps"]);
```

Comment: Ya, I've got the data now, thanks. What I want to do next is split the paragraph after delimiter **.,**. How can I do that?

Comment: You can split any string like this: 
var responseString = str.split(".");
where str is the variable in which your paragraph is stored and you can specify any delimiter.